# How to pass an array in formData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using formData and trying to pass an array that receives it in .Net Core backend
this is my array that i try to send truck.StateTruck:

```
{
  0: {StaId: 6}
  1: {StaId: 7}
  2: {StaId: 8}
  3: {StaId: 9}
}
```

this is my method to send my data that I try to send only the StaId and its value:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.set('DriId',truck.DriId);
formData.set('TruExdate',truck.TruExdate);
formData.set('TruAddress',truck.TruAddress);
formData.set('TruCity',truck.TruCity);
formData.set('TraId',truck.TraId);
formData.set('TruZip',truck.TruZip);
formData.set('TruYear',truck.TruYear);
formData.set('TruMake',truck.TruMake);
formData.set('TruType',truck.TruType);
formData.set('TruFuel',truck.TruFuel);
formData.set('TruAxles',truck.TruAxles);
formData.set('TruVin',truck.TruVin);
formData.set('TruDocurl',truck.TruDocurl);
formData.set('TraUnit',truck.TraUnit);
formData.set('TraMake',truck.TraMake);
formData.set('TraYear',truck.TraYear);
formData.set('TtyId',truck.TtyId);
formData.set('TraIntmaterial',truck.TraIntmaterial);
formData.set('TraEquipament',truck.TraEquipament);
formData.set('TraOption',truck.TraOption);
formData.set('Fichero',truck.Fichero);
formData.append('StateTruck',JSON.stringify(truck.StateTruck));
```

when printing to the console using the `console.log (formData.getAll ('StateTruck'));` I see

```
["[{"StaId":6},{"StaId":7},{"StaId":8},{"StaId":9}]"]
```

and my backend expects this structure:

```
public class TruckRequest
    {
        public int TruId { get; set; }
        public int? DriId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TruExdate { get; set; }
        public string TruAddress { get; set; }
        public string TruCity { get; set; }
        public int? TraId { get; set; }
        public string TruZip { get; set; }
        public string TruYear { get; set; }
        public string TruMake { get; set; }
        public string TruType { get; set; }
        public string TruFuel { get; set; }
        public string TruAxles { get; set; }
        public string TruVin { get; set; }
        public string TruDocurl { get; set; }

        public string TraUnit { get; set; }
        public string TraMake { get; set; }
        public string TraYear { get; set; }
        public int? TtyId { get; set; }
        public string TraIntmaterial { get; set; }
        public string TraEquipament { get; set; }
        public string TraOption { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Fichero { get; set; }
        public string TruUregistro { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TruUfecha { get; set; }
        public string TruUupdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TruUupdatefecha { get; set; }
        public string TruEstado { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StateTruck> StateTruck { get; set; }    
}


public partial class StateTruck
{
    public int SruId { get; set; }
    public int? StaId { get; set; }
    public string SruUregistro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SruUfecha { get; set; }
    public string SruUupdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SruUupdatefecha { get; set; }
    public string SruEstado { get; set; }
    public int? TruId { get; set; }

}
```

How can I give it the correct format so that it can be received?

Answer (score 0):

if you need the value converted to string, you may use

e.g.

```
formData.set('TruYear', truck.TruYear.toString());
```

for integer, e.g.

```
formData.set('TruYear', parseInt(truck.TruYear));
```

All these are passed as formData to your backend, **your server should create the parser to convert** to the right format, and **to validate** it is the right format.

**Never, trust, anything submitted from frontend.**

Comment: the wish to send is this array formData.append('StateTruck',JSON.stringify(truck.StateTruck));

Answer (score 0):

When console logging out the data you need to parse the first element in the array received from `formData.getAll ('StateTruck')`. The following should help in your scenario:

`console.log(JSON.parse(formData.getAll("StateTruck")[0]))`

Comment: What I am going to send is not only one item, but several        public virtual ICollection<StateTruck> StateTruck { get; set; }

Comment: `formData.getAll("StateTruck")` returns an array of values associated with the given key which is why the first element needs to be accessed, the value will still be an array of objects. You may want to use `formData.get("StateTruck")` instead. The resulting array will still be the same

`console.log(JSON.parse(formData.get("StateTruck")))`

Comment: print console VM29356:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 of  console.log(JSON.parse(formData.getAll("StateTruck")[0]))

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to use FormData to pass value (include the object array) from client side to server side (Web API). If that is the case, you could refer to the following sample code:

Client side (using JQuery Ajax to call the web API method):

```
    $(function () {
        //Submit Main Form.
        $("#btnCreate").click(function (event) {
            //Prevent Default Region.
            event.preventDefault();
            //define an array to store the StateTruck
            var statetruce = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                statetruce.push({ StaId: i });
            }

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.set('DriId', 101); 
            formData.set('TruAddress', "Address 1");
            formData.set('TruCity', "city A");
            formData.set('TraId', 1011);
            formData.set('TruZip', "zip12");
            formData.set('TruYear', "years "); 
            formData.append('StateTruck', JSON.stringify(statetruce));  
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/TestAPI',
                type: "post",
                async: true,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    // window.location.href = response;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Based on the Array Object's property to create a View Model, it is used to Deserialize the  array object.

Code in the Web API method:

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormCollection collection)
    {

        var DriId = collection["DriId"].ToString();
        var TruAddress = collection["TruAddress"].ToString();

        var StateTruck = collection["StateTruck"].ToString();
        //deserialize the object
        var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<StateTruckViewModel>>(StateTruck);

        //do something
        return Ok("success");
    }
```

Then debug screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: I am not using ajax I am doing this process with reactjs and axios

Comment: There is no way to convert by object that there are a lot of fields and passing it one by one is very laborious